# PHP + MSSQL ON IIS is Extremely Slow

Tags: php, sql-server, performance, iis

I have a problem while trying to connect to local MS SQL server using PHP on IIS . the mssql_connect takes 2-3 seconds to execute and it slows down the page execution , the same also with persistent connection using mssql_pconnect .

i tried the same page with Apache on the same machine it execute fast , but with IIS it's very slow.
 so what's the solution for this problem ?

### Server INFO :

- Windows: Windows Server 2008
- MSSQL : Microsoft sql server 2008
- IIS Version : 7.5
- MSSQL Library version : FreeTDS

any help will be much appreciated , Thanks

Comment: PHP is primarily linux based. Way faster on linux systems. If its performance you are looking for, go for aspx. If you need support from community, go for php. If at all you want to use php on a windows box, apache (wamp) is the way to go.

I suggest you start using aspx on IIS server and reap maximum benefits. P.S. I am a PHP-guy :)

Comment: PHP is compiled from C++ into a windows executable, nothing to do with Linux????

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the much more memory efficient MSSQL driver for PHP from Microsoft? The current one that we ship with PHP haven't had a maintainer for years and barely anyone fixing bugs to keep the extension up to pair with other core extensions.

Heres a link to the sqlsrv extension, that works with PDO aswell:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20098

Project page:
http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/

And documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting by providing `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`? I found that using `localhost` in some places can cause a 2-3 second delay while using the localhost-IP (or server name) does not have this problem.